# Difference between two transform broadcasters

Tags: ros, namespace, multi-robot, frames

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the difference between the following transform broadcasters in a multi-robot simulation:

```
1. br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "/map", "odom"));

2. br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "map", "odom"));
```

I have included the transform broadcaster in two namespaces: `robot_1 (tf_prefix="robot_1")` and `robot_2(tf_prefix="robot_2")`. I want to use a common map frame. Which of the above two command should I use to get transform of both robots w.r.t. global /map frame?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198689/difference-between-two-transform-broadcasters/) by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2014-12-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure about this, but I believe they are identical. You should insert the tf_prefix yourself, i.e. retrieve the param and prefix the odom frames.

It is easy to test though: Just subscribe raw /tf and check what frames are send in the messages.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2014-12-02**:
The first broadcaster provides me the desired common /map frame. The `tf_prefix` does not affect the name of map frame when declared as `/map`.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-12-02**:
And I believe the same happens, when you use "map" unless you add the tf_prefix manually. Just try it out.

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2014-12-02**:
yes. that's true. Setting tf_prefix manually converts the frames to /tf_prefix/frame_name.